# eachParallel() throwing groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when using GPars

Tags: java, groovy, missingmethodexception, gpars

I'm currently trying to use GPars to concurrently go through a directory system in a DFS manner. This is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<String> visited = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>())

void scheduleDirectory(String rootStartPath) {
    GParsPool.withPool(4) {
        dfs(rootStartPath)
    }
}

void dfs(String path) {
    visited << path

    // This will retrieve what's in the path directory
    // Each object inside listResult shows the name, path, type (directory or file), etc.
    def listResult = dao.listDirectory(tenant, namespace, path)
    if(listResult) {
        listResult.eachParallel {
            def childPath = getPath(it)   // Get the path of the listResult
            if(it.type == "directory") {
                if(!visited.contains(childPath)) {
                    dfs(childPath)
                }
            }
            else if(it.type == "object") {
                // Do some other processing stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to call eachParallel() with a closure, I get this on my stacktrace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.eachParallel() is applicable for argument types: (com.abc.service.DFSService$_dfs_closure2) values: [com.abc.service.DFSService$_dfs_closure2@7d016471]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:72) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:48) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at com.abc.service.DFSService.dfs(DFSService.groovy:86) ~[main/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at com.abc.service.DFSService$_dfs_closure2.doCall(DFSService.groovy:97) ~[main/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427) ~[groovy-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at groovyx.gpars.pa.CallClosure.call(CallClosure.java:47) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at groovyx.gpars.pa.ClosureMapper.op(ClosureMapper.java:36) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.AbstractParallelAnyArray$OOMPap.leafTransfer(AbstractParallelAnyArray.java:2255) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.PAS$FJOMap.atLeaf(PAS.java:258) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.PAS$FJBase.internalCompute(PAS.java:118) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.PAS$FJBase.compute(PAS.java:106) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at jsr166y.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:148) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:305) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:575) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:755) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:617) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:369) ~[jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
```

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929161/groovy-gpars-and-missingmethodexception-when-calling-eachparallel) so I thought maybe it was my build.gradle file but that doesn't seem to be the case either. My gradle.build file is:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4',
            'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1'
            ...
    }
...
```

Comment: What happens if you use just `each`?

Comment: @chrylis It runs fine but the point is to run it in parallel because of performance

Comment: I understand you want to run it in parallel. I'm asking as a debugging step, because you didn't mention whether you still got an error then.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If 9 or higher, have you imported the *module* as well as the dependency?

Comment: I do get an error but it's a com.amazonaws.SdkClientException which I believe is related to my connection with the VPN. But other than that, it's running fine. I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by placing the `GParsPool.withPool()` outside of the `dfs` method will cause the recursive calls to `dfs` to fall outside of the scope of GPars and the result will be that the `listResult` in the nested calls will not have the `eachParallel()` method available.

Your issue is fixed if you move the `GParsPool.withPool(4)` closure within the `dfs` method and the results will run in parallel, limited to 4 threads as expected:

```
ArrayList<String> visited = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>())

void scheduleDirectory(String rootStartPath) {
    dfs(rootStartPath)
}

void dfs(String path) {
    GParsPool.withPool(4) {
        visited << path

        // This will retrieve what's in the path directory
        // Each object inside listResult shows the name, path, type (directory or file), etc.
        def listResult = dao.listDirectory(tenant, namespace, path)
        if(listResult) {
            listResult.eachParallel {
                def childPath = getPath(it)   // Get the path of the listResult
                if(it.type == "directory") {
                    if(!visited.contains(childPath)) {
                        dfs(childPath)
                    }
                }
                else if(it.type == "object") {
                    // Do some other processing stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```